# save data in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Help me please with knockout.js problem:

Why variable currentObject is undefinded ? How I can save current selected object in some variable ?

I have follow html view for down drop list:

```
 <select data-placeholder="Select object" class="span5" id="objects" data-bind="options: objects, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: currentObject">
                    <option></option>
 </select>
```

ModelView:

```
function baseViewModel() {
    self.objects = ko.observableArray([]);

    ...

    self.currentObject = ko.observable();

    ...



    self.func = function() {

        //allert(self.objects()[0].Name) //return correct Name
        alert(self.currentObject().Name) //returns undefinded


    }

}
```

Comment: what does `self.currentObject()` return?

Comment: Are you actually defining `self`? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: "var self = this; " before "self.objects = ko.observableArray([]);"

Comment: I thought that variable currentObject will be dynamic change when I select  item in down drop list

Comment: When does your `self.func` gets called? Can you maybe put together a jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your data-bind, you have `value: currentObject` which will indeed do a two-way bind between currentObject and the select's *value*.

The select's value is set to the `Id` field of the selected option's object (because of `optionsValue: 'Id'` in your data-bind).
So, currentObject will be set to the Id field of the selected object, and that's why doing `.Name` gets you undefined.

I suggest not using `optionsValue` at all, this way KO will handle the value and it will be as if the value of the selectbox is the actual selected object, and `value: currentObject` will correctly set currentObject to the selected object. (And if you do want to use `optionsValue`, then know that currentObject will be set to the object's field, not the object itself)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/KXhem/78/